# creating a new a name record to point to AWS instance on port 4502 / 4503

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cname

I am trying to create a new A name record to point to my AEM instance on AWS.

On AWS AEM is installed on port 4502 and 4503. Author is on 4502 and publisher on 4503.

But I cannot create a A name or C name record that points to the ip address of the AWS e2 instance the add :4503

Can anyone suggest a way around this? should I be setting up something else within AWS that has a new IP address that points to the other one with a port?

I have other things setup on this AWS instance that uses port 80.

I appreciate the help as I am pretty new to all of this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a / cnames do not work at port level. 
you can use the same name and just open up the ports in the Security Group (and/or) create another load balancer. this should do the trice.

Comment: hi.. Sorry can you explain a bit more? I dont really understand - the ports are open that is why I can access from http://myawsip.com:4503

Comment: sure. as said above you cannot do what you are attempting to do with DNS. if you just want to get to the host you can use the port directly (seems that you figured this part out). If you want a different name that reaches the host:port via another host:port (e.g. test101.mydomain.com:80 should go to real name.mydomain:4503) the easiest way to do this is to setup a load balancer (ELB). Point the CNAME you want to use at the load balancer and have the instance port be 4503. put your host behind the load balancer.